# Custom the scale function in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I would like to map 1-1000 to 1-190, my map function is:

```
f(x) = { x                     if 1<=x and x<=100,
         100 + (x-100)/10      if 100 < x <= 1000           }
```

How should I do?

Comment: Why do you want to use a mapping and not a function that returns a corresponding value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, got the solution by tracing the source code:

```
d3.scale.linear().domain([1, 100, 1000]).range([1, 100,190]) //poly-linear
```

Comment: In fact I'm using rickshaw.js, which is a javascript toolkit for creating time series graph and is based on d3.js. And it only support the by-linear scale, so I need to read the documentation of d3.js and modify it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with 3d.js, but this is how I would do it in regular JS

```
function toNewScale( x ) {

    return Math.round( x / 1000 * 190 );
}
```

if this is what you were asking.

Comment: I'm afraid that your map function is different from mine.

Comment: I know, I dont know how to do mappings in 3d.js & I cant easily find info about mapping. I guess I'm suggesting to use a function instead of a map.

Comment: Thanks for your suggesting, but I need to pass a d3.scale function for scaling. Thanks :)