# d3 unevenly distributed scaling

Tags: d3.js, axes

any suggestions for drawing axes with unequal spacing between the values. For instance I am currently drawing axes using:

```
yScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 60000]).range([height, 0])
```

I need more spacing between 0 and 5000 than distributing all the data points equally

Answer (score 9):

Try using a [polylinear scale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13641944/custom-the-scale-function-in-d3-js):

```
yScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 5000, 60000]).range([height, height/2, 0])
```

The range (0, 5000) and (5000, 60000) will both be given the same amount of space.