# Uneven widths in a hierarchical partition

Tags: d3.js, hierarchy

I am new to D3.js. I need to draw a representation of my hierarchical data with, say, a partition layout. But I would like the width of a given column to depend on a certain function of its depth in the hierarchy.

For instance, in https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2e73ec84221cb9773f4c, the relative widths of the five columns would be 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.3, 0.3, respectively, instead of 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2.

If I understand correctly [d3.js uneven scaling with rangeBands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24918221/d3-js-uneven-scaling-with-rangebands), I can't. But, this question is almost 3 years old. Is it possible today?

Of course, I could manually tweak the `x` and `dx` attributes populated by `partition()`. But I guess there exists a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. It turns out this can be done with a scale:

Instead of:

```
x_scale = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, WIDTH])
```

Just do:

```
x_scale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.7]).range([0, 0.2*WIDTH, 0.3*WIDTH, 0.4*WIDTH, 0.7*WIDTH])
```

Works like a charm.