# Removing empty space in D3 y axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, charts, visualization

I'm generating a line chart with d3js. Some of the data is overlapping each others. Like this:

[image]

(See those 4 lines at the bottom).This is how those 4 lines looks like after removing the rest of the lines:

[image]

What I want to do is to somehow remove those empty vertical spaces where there's no data present.

Any possible way to do it?

Comment: Can you provide code or link to jsfiddle?

Comment: By the way, have a look at this example. Maybe it will give you any ideas how to solve your task: http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/e34791a32a54e015f57d

Comment: So my data is arranged in zones. There could be 1 zone to as many as 50 zones. And all zones have different temperature range. Here's a fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/wz1fdbxd/78/

Comment: Check the chart1. Val1 and val2 are almost looks like a straight line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is a broken Y axis. Something like this:

[image]

Before we continue, it's very important that you **tell the user** that the axis is broken, clearly and explicitly. And add some symbol to the axis showing that it is broken:

[image]

Otherwise, you are **lying with data!**

Back to your question: to create a broken Y axis you just need to add midpoints to your y scale (both in the domain and in the range).

Let's see this in a demo. This is a basic chart, you can see that there is a bunch of lines at the low end (between `0` and `12` in the y axis), just like your chart:

```js
var w = 400, h = 300;
var data = [1, 3, 4, 7, 10, 11, 12, 160, 180, 210, 230];
var svg = d3.select("body")
 .append("svg")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h);
var scale = d3.scaleLinear()
 .domain([0, 230])
  .range([h - 4, 4]);
var colors = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);
var lines = svg.selectAll(null)
 .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("line")
  .attr("x1", 30)
  .attr("x2", w)
  .attr("y1", function(d){ return scale(d)})
  .attr("y2", function(d){ return scale(d)})
  .style("stroke", function(d, i){ return colors(i)})
  .style("shape-rendering", "crispEdges");
var axis = d3.axisLeft(scale)(svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(30,0)"))
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Very hard to tell the values here. So, let's break the Y axis, creating midpoints in the scale. In my demo, I did this:

```
var scale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 15, 150, 230])
    .range([h - 4, h / 2 , h / 2, 4]);
```

That means that all the values between `15` and `150` will be positioned at the same point in the scale.

Here is the result, using the **same data**:

```js
var w = 500,
  h = 400;
var data = [1, 3, 4, 7, 10, 11, 12, 160, 180, 210, 230];
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h);
var scale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 15, 150, 230])
  .range([h - 4, h / 2, h / 2, 4]);
var colors = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);
var lines = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("line")
  .attr("x1", 30)
  .attr("x2", w)
  .attr("y1", function(d) {
    return scale(d)
  })
  .attr("y2", function(d) {
    return scale(d)
  })
  .style("stroke", function(d, i) {
    return colors(i)
  })
  .style("shape-rendering", "crispEdges");
var axis = d3.axisLeft(scale).tickValues([0, 5, 10, 15, 160, 180, 200, 220])(svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(30,0)"))
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Of course, I had to set the tick values explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Non-linear y scaling can solve your issue.
For example, *[.scalePow](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#power-scales)* or *[.logScale](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#log-scales)* instead of *.scaleLinear*:

```
var y = d3.scalePow()
  .exponent(0.3)
  .domain([0, 1000, 10000, 60000])
  .range([height, 0]);
```

See [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Dimmy/ztL8z4xj/1/).

Comment: I've been trying to play around with it but it's not working for my data set, I believe. Maybe it has something to do with my x-axis in in datetime format? Here's how my data looks like -> https://i.imgur.com/yDb8Fl8.png

Comment: Isn't the fiddle that you provided containing your data set?

Comment: Not really. The values are pretty similar, but for time, I didn't know how to generate random datetime value so just stick with integer(UNIX).

Comment: I ended up using poly-linear scale. http://bl.ocks.org/herrstucki/5403383  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13641944/custom-the-scale-function-in-d3-js

Comment: I'm curious about your end result; can you share it with us?